# Postgresql adding column with date datatype

Tags: postgresql

I have added a column to existing table with datatype as `date`, but when I do `describe table name` I'm seeing the new column with datatype as `timestamp`. can anyone please help me on this.

Comment: Show us the sql for adding the column.

Comment: alter table table_name add column column_name date;

Comment: Strange. I tried it and i got the type 'date' when describing the table.

Comment: what postgresql version ar you running?

Comment: version:9.6.3 and PGadmin4 and I'm connecting through SQL Workbench

Comment: `describe table` is oracle? workbench is mysql? 9.6.3 is postgres? what are you really doing?

Comment: I'm Using PostgreSQL as a database and connecting through SQL Workbench (its a independent tool which allows you to connect to all databases).

Comment: any thoughts please

Answer (score 0):

Just write this query this implement nullable "date" type column.

```sql
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD COLUMN column_name DATE;
```